# How to update a table on the basis of difference of current time and column time 

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `node_status` which has three columns:

1. `id (int)`
2. `status (bit)`
3. `modifiedtime (smalldatetime)`

I want to run a query on it such that if any row in the table contains a `modifiedtime` value which is more than 5 minutes before the current time then the `status` column set to 0 (false).

Can any body tell me how to do this? (using SQL Server)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to do a query based on the current time you can use getdate(), and use the dateadd function to add or remove amounts of time from a date. As such:

```
update 
     node_status 
set 
     status = 0 
where 
     modifiedtime < dateadd(minute, -5, getdate())
```

Answer (score 3):

The query

```
UPDATE node_status
SET [Status] = 0
WHERE DATEDIFF(n, ModifiedTime, CURRENT_TIMETAMP) >= 5
```

will do the job, however, if your node_status table is large, then the performance will be lousy due to table / index scans. If you have an index on ModifiedTime:

```
DECLARE @ThresholdTime DATETIME
SET @ThresholdTime = DATEADD(n, -5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

UPDATE node_status
SET [Status] = 0
WHERE ModifiedTime <= @ThresholdTime
```

or even better, if the majority of records have node_status = 0 (i.e. selectivity)

```
UPDATE node_status
SET [Status] = 0
WHERE ModifiedTime <= @ThresholdTime
    AND [Status] = 1 -- You've stated that status is a bit - I've assumed not nullable.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function to compute the date/time before five minutes and then compare the modifiedtime column to this value:

```
UPDATE node_status SET status = 0 WHERE modifiedtime <= dateadd(minute, -5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```